# Testing Hashem (for Monetary Gain)

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, money, mysticism-kabbalah, rabbis

If I remember right, [The Legacy of Maran Rav Aharon Kotler](http://www.feldheim.com/the-legacy-of-maran-rav-aharon-kotler.html) describes how a son tests his father's ability to sense if a glass has been *tovel*ed in a *mikveh*. The father passed the test consistently.

Generally, we are [not allowed to test Hashem](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95_%D7%98%D7%96).

How could the otherwise observant son do this?

Would it be allowed to use such ability to win [The Million Dollar Challenge](http://web.randi.org/the-million-dollar-challenge.html)?

Maybe Hashem would let because such a price could provide a significant boost to Torah organizations.

Comment: I don't get it. When you say "his father", are you referring to his [father in heaven](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_the_Father#Judaism)? If not, then how does testing his father's ability to sense _t'vila_ constitute testing _Hashem_?

Comment: @msh210 Obviously, regular abilities of a person does not allow him to sense t'vila. Hashem clearly allows this by a supernatural usage of his name, in what one could classify as a minor on-demand miracle .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would qualify as the testing of Hashem which is being prohibited by that verse.

The Ramban there writes (with my rough translation):

> פירוש כאשר נסיתם במסה שלא תאמר אם יש ה' בקרבנו לעשות לנו נסים או שנצליח בהיותנו עובדים לפניו ונשבע לחם ונהיה טובים נשמור תורתו
>
> Meaning, like they tested Hashem in Massa, that one shouldn't say "if Hashem takes care of me and does miracles, then I'll serve him [and if not, then I won't]."

and

> אין ראוי לעבדו על מנת לקבל פרס אלא אולי ימצא בעבודתו ולכתו בדרכי התורה צער ואסון וראוי שיקבל הכל במשפט צדק
>
> It is not appropriate to serve Hashem on condition that He reward us, but we have to accept that we might have hard times and difficulty, and accept it.

Testing Hashem (in that context) means making your serving Him dependent on His proving Himself to you or appeasing you.  If you want to do tricks, but will be serving Hashem whether or not your tricks work, then there is nothing prohibited by that prohibition in doing such.

Comment: So doing it for monetary gain would be acceptable, assuming one would serve Hashem regardless?

Comment: @NBZ I don't think YeZ was trying to answer that part of the question. I think he was answering the question of "How could the otherwise observant son do this?"

Answer (score 0):

Nope. *Don't test* means *don't test.* Not *don't test --- BUT... it's different if you think it would be the most gishmacky thing since sliced kishka.*

Philosophically, there's enough room for people to believe, and for people to not believe. I don't see why now all of a sudden with a million dollars and a wet glass, suddenly G-d would change that.

Comment: See edit.​​​​​​